# Возможно создать MP3 файл с помощью звуков

Tags: файлы, rust, mp3

**Добрый день**
**Вопрос:** Могу ли я создавать MP3 файлы на языке программирования Rust? (Это не проблема, а вопрос)

**Информация:** Я хочу сделать программу, которая будет создавать MP3 файл со звуками. Возможно ли это? Главное: мне не нужно воспроизводить MP3 файл, мне нужно создать его из звуков. В интернете я не смог найти ответ, по этому решил задать вопрос уже сам.

- Если нужно, могу привести пример, но сразу пишу - что мой пример может быть не понятен для вас.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Формально говоря, MP3, или любой другой формат файла, на Rust создать не проблема ( как и на любом другом языке общего назначения).

Грубо, если язык позволяет создавать файлы, то и `MP3` со своим содержимым в нем создать можно.

Для исследовательских целей, я бы не приставал к `MP3`, как к формату. Если цель программы - создавать звуки, так и создавайте файл `WAV` - он намного проще по структуре. А перегнать потом в любой формат можно любой внешней утилитой.

Это позволит вам избавиться от необходимости разбираться с MP3 под Rust, а сразу заняться основной задачей - генерацией звуков.

Comment: @gbg Хорошо, но тогда как создать `.wav` файл? Можете ли вы написать код для примера, или предоставить видео, где показано как создать `.wav` файл из звуков (можно сказать: как записать `.wav` файл, из звуков) на языке "Rust"

Comment: Откуда должны браться звуки?

Comment: Я конечно мог не правильно вас понять, но все же. Моя идея для программы - брать `.wav` файлы из папок, и делать из них один `.wav` файл.

Comment: То есть вам нужно что-то вроде музыкального редактора с возможностью накладывать звуки друг на друга?

Comment: Ну как, у меня есть другая задумка, чтобы они шли с задержкой. Пример: Проиграл первый звук, задержка 1 секунда - проиграл второй звук. (если надо, я могу полностью написать свою идею, но возможно вы можете не понять меня)

Comment: Описыывйте всю идею пожалуйста.

Comment: Моя идея такова: У меня есть файл, в котором есть данные, эти данные записывались только когда пользователь кликал, все эти данные расположены так: "Позиция, клик". Я хочу сделать программу которая будет создавать один полноценный `.wav` файл, из других `.wav` файлов. Но эти другие `.wav` файлы, будут находится в папках которая будет в папке. (Пример: folder/folder1 и folder/folder2), Там будут находится файлы но мне нужно чтобы они были разными (чтобы производились разные звуки, допустим: folder/folder1/0.wav, затем folder/folder2/0.wav. Затем folder/folder1/1.wav, folder/folder2/1.wav).